# Get all documents involved in a transaction when using change streams in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

When using [change streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) in MongoDB you typically get one document at a time. I'm looking for a way to get all documents that were involved in a *transaction*.

For example, if I write two documents, `A` and `B` in transaction 1, is there a way for me, by using a change stream, to get all documents that were written in transaction 1 (`A` and `B`)?

I've read in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) that mongodb adds the `txnNumber` and `lsid`, but I don't know how to use this to get all documents in the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All change events with the same txnNumber and lsid are part of the same transaction. Once an event contains txnNumber and lsid, add subsequent events to the same transaction until either value changes.

Test in Ruby:

```
require 'mongo'

Mongo::Logger.logger.level = Logger::INFO

client = Mongo::Client.new(['localhost:14420'], database: 'f')

coll = client['foo']
cs = coll.watch

client.start_session do |s|
  s.with_transaction do
    coll.insert_one({a: 1}, session: s)
    coll.insert_one({a: 2}, session: s)
  end

  coll.insert_one({a: 3}, session: s)

  s.with_transaction do
    coll.insert_one({a: 4}, session: s)
    coll.insert_one({a: 5}, session: s)
  end
end

enum = cs.to_enum
p enum.next
p enum.next
puts
p enum.next
puts
p enum.next
p enum.next
```

Result:

```
{"txnNumber"=>1, "lsid"=>{"id"=><BSON::Binary:0x760 type=uuid data=0x70cefa5f02e443f5...>, "uid"=><BSON::Binary:0x780 type=generic data=0xe3b0c44298fc1c14...>}, "_id"=>{"_data"=>"825FC18030000000012B022C0100296E5A1004C1D5E8B7F0814A5AAB500B14E1B37F2146645F696400645FC180302C97A6366654FEF50004"}, "operationType"=>"insert", "clusterTime"=>#<BSON::Timestamp:0x000055ce9a701c50 @seconds=1606516784, @increment=1>, "fullDocument"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5fc180302c97a6366654fef5'), "a"=>1}, "ns"=>{"db"=>"f", "coll"=>"foo"}, "documentKey"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5fc180302c97a6366654fef5')}}
{"txnNumber"=>1, "lsid"=>{"id"=><BSON::Binary:0x800 type=uuid data=0x70cefa5f02e443f5...>, "uid"=><BSON::Binary:0x820 type=generic data=0xe3b0c44298fc1c14...>}, "_id"=>{"_data"=>"825FC18030000000012B022C01002B026E5A1004C1D5E8B7F0814A5AAB500B14E1B37F2146645F696400645FC180302C97A6366654FEF60004"}, "operationType"=>"insert", "clusterTime"=>#<BSON::Timestamp:0x000055ce9a701200 @seconds=1606516784, @increment=1>, "fullDocument"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5fc180302c97a6366654fef6'), "a"=>2}, "ns"=>{"db"=>"f", "coll"=>"foo"}, "documentKey"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5fc180302c97a6366654fef6')}}

{"_id"=>{"_data"=>"825FC18030000000032B022C0100296E5A1004C1D5E8B7F0814A5AAB500B14E1B37F2146645F696400645FC180302C97A6366654FEF70004"}, "operationType"=>"insert", "clusterTime"=>#<BSON::Timestamp:0x000055ce9a700cd8 @seconds=1606516784, @increment=3>, "fullDocument"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5fc180302c97a6366654fef7'), "a"=>3}, "ns"=>{"db"=>"f", "coll"=>"foo"}, "documentKey"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5fc180302c97a6366654fef7')}}

{"txnNumber"=>3, "lsid"=>{"id"=><BSON::Binary:0x840 type=uuid data=0x70cefa5f02e443f5...>, "uid"=><BSON::Binary:0x860 type=generic data=0xe3b0c44298fc1c14...>}, "_id"=>{"_data"=>"825FC18030000000042B022C0100296E5A1004C1D5E8B7F0814A5AAB500B14E1B37F2146645F696400645FC180302C97A6366654FEF80004"}, "operationType"=>"insert", "clusterTime"=>#<BSON::Timestamp:0x000055ce9a7004e0 @seconds=1606516784, @increment=4>, "fullDocument"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5fc180302c97a6366654fef8'), "a"=>4}, "ns"=>{"db"=>"f", "coll"=>"foo"}, "documentKey"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5fc180302c97a6366654fef8')}}
{"txnNumber"=>3, "lsid"=>{"id"=><BSON::Binary:0x880 type=uuid data=0x70cefa5f02e443f5...>, "uid"=><BSON::Binary:0x900 type=generic data=0xe3b0c44298fc1c14...>}, "_id"=>{"_data"=>"825FC18030000000042B022C01002B026E5A1004C1D5E8B7F0814A5AAB500B14E1B37F2146645F696400645FC180302C97A6366654FEF90004"}, "operationType"=>"insert", "clusterTime"=>#<BSON::Timestamp:0x000055ce9a6efac8 @seconds=1606516784, @increment=4>, "fullDocument"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5fc180302c97a6366654fef9'), "a"=>5}, "ns"=>{"db"=>"f", "coll"=>"foo"}, "documentKey"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5fc180302c97a6366654fef9')}}
```

Note that txnNumber is used (by the driver) with all write operations performed under sessions (which includes the a:3 insert). But the change stream does not return txnNumber for the corresponding event. And in a transaction, txnNumber stays the same for all operations.